# Centre products image on the wishlist section on the Customer Account dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

Above screenshot as you can see my products image is coming on the left corner i want to make it centre, how can i do it please help.

Comment: please give text-align:cener to parent div and give css to img "float:none;margin:0 auto."

Comment: where can i find it's .css file ?

Comment: Please inspect element on image after you can find  css file name on right side

Comment: <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($item) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(113, 113); ?>" width="113" height="113" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>" />
</a>
i found this code through path finder, can i do anything in this ?

Comment: in this code you can see right side css filepath getting after you can add code in css

Comment: <a class="product-image" style="text-align:cener" href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($item) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(113, 113); ?>" style="float:none;margin:0 auto" width="113" height="113" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>" /> </a> please try this code already added style

Comment: yes i tried same code it didn't work.

Comment: please sent your url i will be check and set